# How to run Scalaz Tasks in parallel

Tags: multithreading, scala, parallel-processing, scalaz

I have a bunch of Scalaz Tasks. Created like this:

```
val tasks = for (i <- 1 to 50) yield {
  Task.delay({
    Thread.sleep(100L)
    println(i)
    i
  })
}

val r = Nondeterminism[Task].gatherUnordered(tasks).run
println(r.mkString(" "))
```

I would expect the tasks to run in parallel. To print numbers in random order, and not to take 5 seconds (there are 50 tasks and 100 millis sleep in each).

However, it is clear that each task takes 100 millis, all of them take 5 seconds, and the created list is ordered.

How to run them in parallel? Where does Task take the thread to run on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.delay` suspends evaluation of its argument, but it doesn't say anything about where the evaluation will happen. You want `Task.apply`, which has the same signature except that it takes an implicit `ExecutorService` that will decide which thread the evaluation will happen in:

```
import scalaz.Nondeterminism, scalaz.concurrent.Task

val tasks = for (i <- 1 to 50) yield {
  Task {
    Thread.sleep(100L)
    println(i)
    i
  }
}

val r = Nondeterminism[Task].gatherUnordered(tasks).run
println(r.mkString(" "))
```

This will use the default `ExecutorService`, which wraps a fixed thread pool. If you want a different strategy, you can either put a different `ExecutorService` into implicit scope, or provide one explicitly in a second argument list for `Task.apply`.